# Merge two layers with different shape reproducing SiamRPN

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to reproduce this paper [SiameseRPN](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Li_High_Performance_Visual_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf) using Keras.
The architecture is presented as below.
[image]

its give this in my code.

```js
Template_input_shape = (127, 127, 3)
Detection_input_shape = (255, 255, 3)


// make the input
input_Template = tf.keras.Input(shape=Template_input_shape)
input_Detection = tf.keras.Input(shape=Detection_input_shape)

// make with alexNet model
processed_Template = alexNet(input_Template) // (6, 6, 256) output
processed_Detection = alexNet(input_Detection) // (22, 22, 256) output

// alexNet represente my model.

// after (if i've well understood) outputs are dispatched over a classification model and regression model


def classification_Branch(input_a, input_b, anchors=5, out=256):
    cls_x = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3)(input_a.output)
    cls_z = keras.layers.Conv2D(out, kernel_size=3)(input_b.output)

cls = classification_Branch(processed_Template, processed_Detection)
rgr = regression_Branch(processed_Template, processed_Detection)
```

I'm falling to understand how can I merge both cnn (cls_x with cls_z etc) to give me the desired output.

```
Keras.layers.concatenate([cls_x, cls_z])
```

doesnt work here because the shape are not the same.
someone can explain me how in my situation can I merge both cnn into one cnn with the desired output.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Keras.layers.concatenate` requires both the Convolutional Layers passed to it to have the same shape.

In this case, you can use `UpSampling Layer`.

For Example, suppose the Shape of `cls_x` is `(None, 80, 128, 8)` and the Shape of `cls_z` is `(None, 40, 64, 8)`, you can use

```
p1 = keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2, 2))(c2)
```

before the step,

`Keras.layers.concatenate([cls_x, cls_z])`.

This will multiply the shape of the `cls_z` by 2 and as a result, Shape of cls_x and cls_z will become equal.

Note: We can pass decimal Sizes like (1.5, 1.5) as well, to `UpSampling2D`, based on our requirement.